# Hide top panel on form

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a way to hide top panel form? I would hide "_,[][],X" from my window form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
You can set ControlBox property to False.
```

Other way:

```
Set MinimizeBox property to False.
Set MaximizeBox property to False.
```

Add this code to your form to disble form CLOSE button.

```
private const int CP_NOCLOSE_BUTTON = 0x200;

protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.ClassStyle = cp.ClassStyle | CP_NOCLOSE_BUTTON;
        return cp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily specify whether or not you want your form to have a MinimizeBox or MaximizeBox - simply set these properties to False at design time.

You cannot hide the X button to close the form unless you make the form borderless - set FormBorderStyle property to None, but bear in mind that you will have to provide some other means for the user to close the form (e.g. by clicking a CommandButton).

EDIT: You can hide the X button by setting the ControlBox property to False, but this will also hide the System menu displayed in the upper left corner of the form. This will mean that the user will not be able to close the form using Alt+F4 keyboard combination.